# How to Insert Commas into a array full of strings

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, split

I am trying to split this array into an RLE format, this means i need to separate the numbers and letters with an comma. does anyone have any ideas? i have tried list.split but cannot get it to work with an array

list.split
pain and suffering

```
linesofRLE = raw_input("How Many Lines Of Code Do You Wish To enter:")
        if linesofRLE < 2:
            print 'sorry needs more than 2 lines'
            break
        else:
            print 'ok'
            linesofRLE = int(linesofRLE)
            userRLE = []
            for d in range (linesofRLE):
                enterRLE = raw_input("enter your line of RLE")
                brokenRLE = ([enterRLE[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(enterRLE), 3)]) 
                userRLE.append(brokenRLE)
                print userRLE
                userRLE = [userRLE]
                print userRLE
```

this code should output an array like this:

```
[[[['09g']], [3], ['90h']], [3], ['79g']]
```

Comment: Please format your code. It is not readable. Also add your input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this small amount of code:

```
    from itertools import groupby
def openingthefile():
    myfile=open('LogoRLE.txt','r')
    details=myfile.read()
    myfile.close()
    #print details
    return details



def encode(input_string):
    #print
    return [(len(list(g)), k) for k,g in groupby(input_string)]

file_contents = openingthefile()
file_contents.split()
print file_contents
def decode(lst):
    #print lst
    return ''.join(c * n for n,c in lst)

res_array =  encode(file_contents)
variable2=""
for i in res_array:
    if i[1]=="\n":
        variable2+= i[1]
    else:
        variable2+=str('%02d' % i[0])+i[1]

#print variable2

print "pppppppppppp"

#file_contents = openingthefile()
#print file_contents
res_string =  decode(res_array)
#res_array =  decode(file_contents)
print "pppppppppppp"
print res_string
```